# dask out-of-core matrix multiply scheduling

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication, h5py, dask

I'm trying to compute the matrix product Y=XX^T for a matrix X of size 10,000 * 800,000. The matrix X is stored on-disk in an h5py file. The resulting Y should be a 10,000*10,000 matrix stored in the same h5py file. Here is a reproducible sample code.

```
import dask.array as da
from blaze import into

into("h5py:///tmp/dummy::/X", da.ones((10**4, 8*10**5), chunks=(10**4,10**4)))
x = into(da.Array, "h5py:///tmp/dummy::/X", chunks=(10**4,10**4)))
y = x.dot(x.T)
into("h5py:///tmp/dummy::/Y", y)
```

I expected this computation to go smoothly as each (10,000*10,000) chunk should be individually transposed, followed by a dot product and then summed up to the final result. However, running this computation fills both my RAM and swap memory until the process eventually gets killed.

Here is a sample of the computation graph plotted with dot_graph: [Computation graph sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PERMZ.jpg)

According to the sheduling doc that http: //dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduling-policy.html
I would expect the upper tensordot intermediary results to be summed up one by one into the last sum result as soon as they have been individually computed. This would free the memory of these tensordot intermediary results, so that we would not face memory errors.

Playing around with a smaller toy example:

```
from dask.diagnostics import Profiler, CacheProfiler, ResourceProfiler

# Experiment on a (1,0000 * 5,000) matrix X split into 500 chunks of size (1,000 * 10)
x = into(da.Array, "h5py:///tmp/dummy::/X", chunks=(10**3,10)))[:10**3,5000]
y = x.T.dot(x)
with Profiler() as prof, CacheProfiler() as cprof, ResourceProfiler() as rprof:
    into("h5py:///tmp/dummy::/X", y)
rprof.visualize()
```

I get the following display:
[Ressource profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OtfI.jpg)

Where the green bar represents the sum operation, while yellow and purple bars represent respectively get_array and tensordot operations. This seems to indicate that the sum operation waits for all intermediary tensordot operations to be performed before summing them. This would also explain my process running out of memory and getting killed.

So my questions are:

- Is that the normal behavior of the sum operation?
- Is there a way to force it to compute intermediary sums before all
  the intermediary tensordot products are computed and kept in memory?
- If not, is there a work around that does not involve spilling to disk?

Any help much much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking performing a dense matrix-matrix multiply in small space is hard.  This is because every intermediate chunk will by used by several of the output chunks.

> According to the sheduling doc that http: //dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduling-policy.html I would expect the upper tensordot intermediary results to be summed up one by one into the last sum result as soon as they have been individually computed.

The graph that you have shown has many inputs to a sum function.  Dask will wait until all of those inputs are complete before running the sum function.  The task scheduler has no idea that sum is associative and can be run piece by piece.  This lack of semantic information is the price you pay for using a general task scheduling system like Dask rather than a dedicated linear algebra library.  If your goal is to perform dense linear algebra as efficiently as possible then you might want to look elsewhere; this is a well covered field.

So as written your memory requirements are *at least* `8e5 * 1e4 * dtype.itemsize`, assuming that Dask proceeds in exactly the right order (which it should *mostly* do).

You might try the following:

1. Reduce the chunksize along the non-contracting dimension
2. Use a version of Dask later than 0.14.1 (0.14.2 should be released by May 5th, 2017), where we break down those large sum calls into many smaller ones explicitly in the graph.
3. Use the distributed scheduler, which handles writing data to disk more efficiently.

   ```
   from dask.distributed import Client
   client = Client(processes=False)  # create a local cluster in this process
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MRocklin !

Comment: Regarding option 3, I run into the problem mentioned in https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/927. Hdf5 serialized arrays do not seem to work well with the distributed scheduler. Having a fix for it would allow me to use the live diagnosis/monitoring tools of the distributed scheduler which would be very useful in such case. Also, do you know of a specialized ooc linear algebra library in the  pydata/python ecosystem? I originally started using dask because of its out of core linear algebra feature combined with Numpy API.